# Blocking the navigation to the next screen unless the text input is populated

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to add a condition to my PowerApps app by not allowing users to go to the next screen unless the email is entered in the text input.

I managed to highlight the missing field in red with a warning if the user does not enter an email. Then I managed to stop the navigation from moving forward without the email.

However, it does not let you navigate to the next screen even if you enter an email address.

- Current screen is named ***Cover***
- Next screen is named ***Main Screen***
- Text input for email is named **TextInput1_4**

```
//Email Error creation
UpdateContext({varEmailBlankError:
If(IsBlank(TextInput1_4),true,false)});

//No email generates error and stay
If(varEmailBlankError,
Notify("Fill all the fields to continue", NotificationType.Error));
Navigate('Cover',ScreenTransition.Cover);

//Or Go to next screen if populated
Navigate('Main Screen',ScreenTransition.Cover)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you make this on the OnSelect property of a button. You can simplify your method like this :

```
If( IsBlank(TextInput1_4.Text) , Notify("Fill all the fields to continue", NotificationType.Error) , Navigate('Main Screen',ScreenTransition.Cover) )
```

You don't need to Navigate from your Cover Screen to your Cover Screen at all, just need to check that the value is filled when the user want to go next

Then, if you need the submitted email, pass it to your Main Screen from the context like this :

```
Navigate('Main Screen',ScreenTransition.Cover, {submittedEmail: TextInput1_4.Text})
```

Have a good day

Comment: Nackoo you rock! Thanks for your help!